# create dem from contours for use in another program

Tags: grids-graticules

I need a dem or asc file, not a raster in a gdb, for another program to use.  I have contours, I can make a tin, a tif, but I need the .asc

Comment: You can convert tif to asc with gdal_translate.

Comment: What GIS software are you using? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

There is a module in GRASS that was built to to this: `r.surf.contour`

The best place to learn how to use it is in the grasswiki: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM